# How to prevent user stopping script by CTRL + Z?

Tags: python, background, signals, command-line-interface

I want to prevent the user from going back to the shell prompt by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> from my python command line interpreter script. How can I do that?

Comment: You may be invoking your script in the wrong way. If you open it directly in a new terminal, Ctrl+Z won't do anything; but then, I don't know exactly what it is you're trying to achieve. Think twice before trying to block Ctrl+Z, though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could write a signal handler for SIGTSTP, which is triggered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. Here is an example:

```
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Ctrl+Z pressed, but ignored'

signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler)

while True:
   pass
```

Comment: If you replace `pass` with `raw_input()`, on my machine this breaks: when I press Ctrl-Z, I get a spurious `EOFError`.

Comment: @aix You must have pressed Ctrl+D instead.

Comment: @Chewie: Then there's something different about our setups. For reference, I've added the exception to my answer below.

Comment: @aix It works at least with Python >= 2.7.2, but I get your scenario when testing it with Python 2.6.

Comment: @Chewie: Here, I get with Python 2.7.1. Probably has to do with how the binary is built rather than the version of the interpreter.

Comment: @aix I'm getting the error with Ubuntu's Python 2.7.0, but not with Ubuntu's Python 2.7.2.

Answer (score 3):

The following does the trick on my Linux box:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, signal.SIG_IGN)

for i in xrange(10):
  print raw_input()
```

Installing my own signal handler as suggested by @ZelluX does not work here: pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> while in `raw_input()` gives a spurious `EOFError`:

```
aix@aix:~$ python test.py
^ZCtrl+Z pressed, but ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    raw_input()
EOFError
```

Answer (score 3):

Roughly speaking the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> from a Unix/Linux terminal in cooked or canonical modes will cause the terminal driver to generate a "suspend" signal to the foreground application.

So you have two different overall approaches.  Change the terminal settings or ignore the signal.

If you put the terminal into "raw" mode then you disable that signal generation.  It's also possible to use terminal settings (`import tty` and read the info about tcsetattr, but also read the man pages for ``stty` and terminfo(5) for more details).

ZelluX has already described the simplest signal handling approach.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (which depends on your terminal settings - see stty(1)) then there are other ways the user can return to the command-line.  The only 'real' way of preventing a return to the shell is to remove the shell process by using exec.  So, in the user's startup file (`.profile|.bash_profile|.cshrc`) do:

```
exec python myscript.py
```

Get out of that!