# Testing CTRL-Z in Python script

Tags: python

I'm using a while true infinite loop and I want to be able to test if CTRL-Z is press within the loop because I want to execute some more piece of code before exiting the main program.  A short example would help me.

Comment: Depending on which shell you use this may be impossible; a lot of shells take Ctrl-Z as the "send to background" command, so your script would be sent to the background before it could see those keypresses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent user stopping script by CTRL + Z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174799/how-to-prevent-user-stopping-script-by-ctrl-z)

Comment: Can you use Ctrl-C instead and catch the KeyboardInterrupt exception?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

```
import signal
import time
import os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Ctrl+Z pressed, but ignored')
    os.system('kill -STOP %d' % os.getpid())

signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler)

while True:
    time.sleep(100)
    pass
```

You can send TSTP to the process instead, but then you need to disable or block the signal handler first, so it doesn't get called again.